# Android app + Web API Server + External Authenticators

Tags: c#, android, facebook, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an app for iOS and Android, even tho I started with Android.

My app will allow users to login with FB, Google, or just registering(user, pass, confirmPass).

Now, my app is based (and displays) on information of other users that I will store in a DB and will access it with my Web API Server (C#) with EF.

I wan to use Owin for external authentication services.

What I have right now is some DataSets for different classes. One of them is my custom User.
Now, how do I integrate the login that Owin does with my EF User?

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FBtoken { get; set; }
    public string APIKey { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller:

public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        private NightStirContext db = new NightStirContext();

```
    // GET api/User
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return db.Users.AsEnumerable();
    }

    // GET api/User/5
    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return user;
    }

    // PUT api/User/5
    /// <summary>
    /// When we first register a user, we send all data but the API Key and the FBToken, so they will generate once we create the user.
    /// If FBToken is given, we are signed up with FB; If not, we need to genereate a key and give it back as authentication
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage PutUser(int id, User user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        if (id != user.UserId)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    // POST api/User
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.UserId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }

    // DELETE api/User/5
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteUser(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.Users.Remove(user);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Do I need an AccountController? 
Is there anywhere a guide for this?
Thank you

Comment: Hey, is your project open source? Can I have a look at it?

Comment: It is not but I can walk you through it if you want to.
The web API can be built normally, the problem for me was to log in via c# code handling the credentials and cookies. I can post that if you need it.

Comment: Thanks but now I have shifted to Nancy instead of Web API, but still thanks. Its very simple compared to Web API and necessary for me as I am not well versed with ASP.NET.